# Рандомизация чисел ч.2

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, дорогие программисты. Я студент-первокурсник (3-го начало занятий) на специальности Программная Инженерия. Перед учебой решил немного попрактиковаться с другом в С++ и возник вопрос.

**Описываю суть:** Мы хотим сделать игру, в которой рандомно будет выбираться число от 1 до 100 и будет даваться 5 попыток (к примеру) чтобы угадать число. У нас получилось всё (даже падежи, хотя смахивает на "говнокод"), кроме правильной рандомизации. Число при перезапуске программы остается тем же самым. Могу предоставить код, хотя думаю, что тут итак всё понятно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int x, correct, attempts;
    correct = rand()%100+1;
    attempts = 15;
    string padej;
    cout << "Zdarova! Nachinaem igry\n\n";

start:

    if (attempts <= 15 && attempts >= 5)
    {
        padej = " popytok";
    }
    if (attempts <=4 && attempts >=2)
    {
        padej = " popytki";
    }

    if (attempts == 1)
    {
        padej = " popytka";
    }

    if (attempts == 0)
    {
        cout << "You've lost";
        Sleep(5000);
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "U vas " << attempts << padej << " \n\n";
    cin >> x;

    if(x == correct){
         cout << "Otvet verniy" << endl;
         system ("PAUSE");
         return 0;
    }

    else if(x > correct && x<=100){
        cout << "Visoko!\n\n";
        attempts--;
        goto start;
    }

    else if(x < correct && x >= 1) {
        cout << "Nizko!\n\n";
        attempts--;
        goto start;
    }
    else{
        cerr << "Neopoznannoe chislo\n\n";
        goto start;
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Насчет говнокода связанным с падежами, вот очень хорошая статья:
[Русский Язык. Выбор окончаний][1]


  [1]: http://prog-school.ru/2012/07/russkij-yazyk-vybor-okonchanij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех, известных мне, языках перед использованием rand надо инициировать таймер.
[Гугл подсказывает](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%2B%2B%20rand&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=43ea795387527400&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1366&bih=653), ([Первая же ссылка](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)) что в c++ это делается так

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
```

Comment: Только это не таймер, а rand seed. Начальный элемент последовательности для генерирования случайных чисел (например линейным конгруэнтным методом). Его иногда полезно выводить в лог, что бы потом повторить поведение игры, указав тот же seed.

Comment: И стоит не забывать, что все запуски программы в пределах одной и той же секунды будут работать с одинаковой последовательностью rand().

Для программ, запускаемых руками, это обычно не имеет значения, а вот в цикле из скрипта...

Comment: И, в принципе, можно даже обойтись без генерирования зерна рандомной последовательности, если не особо важно каждый раз после нового запуска программы иметь "эксклюзивную" последовательность.